# Machine level difference in format specifiers %s %d and %c for null byte

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main( int argc ,char** argv) {
    int bugs = 100;
    char nul_byte='\0';
    char care_percentage = bugs * nul_byte;
    printf("Which means you should care %s%%.\n",care_percentage);// 1->prints (null)
    printf("Which means you should care %d%%.\n",care_percentage);// 2->prints 0
    printf("Which means you should care %c%%.\n",care_percentage);// 3->prints 
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is what happens really in the last three statements 1,2 and 3. What happens internally at machine level. How %s takes it to be (null) and %d takes it to be 0 and %c takes it to be nothing while printing.

Can somebody explain these at the depth of machine level?

Comment: It is better to use the correct format string for the various data types then you will always get the expected results.

Comment: "*If a conversion specification is invalid, **the behavior is undefined**. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, **the behavior is undefined**.*" -- C11 Final Draft, §7.21.6.1.9

Answer (score 6):

First of all: This has nothing to do with "machine level". Everything here happens in the runtime or more specifically in the implementation of `printf()`. Moreover all "conversions" happening by using the wrong format specifier is potentially looking for trouble, as you won't have any guarantee these are actually passed/read/interpreted correctly (e.g. due to different lengths), if you're not casting the parameters to the correct types for the format specifiers.

First the calculation:

- `bugs` is set to `100`.
- `nul_byte` is set to `0` (the actual value of `\0`).
- `care_percentage` essentially resolves to doing `100 * 0`, which will be `0` again.

**So, what happens?**

**First case:** This is a special case and I wouldn't necessarily rely on it doing that. You're essentially accessing the string stored at `0x00000000` (which would be an invalid location; the dreaded NULL pointer), you're just lucky it's caught (don't think it's actually defined behavior, but feel free to prove me wrong).

**Second case:** The passed value is read as an integer, so it's 0, because that's the actual value (imagine a (pointer) cast happening there).

**Third case:** The passed value is read as a character, which triggers a special case here as it's not directly inserted into the string as `\0`.

Comment: Some POSIX implementations of printf treat the NULL pointer in a safe way and print `(null)` if the conversion specifier is `%s`. AFAIK the format engine in glibc is implemented like so. It's not standard, though.

Comment: @Mario thanks a lot for the reply
This occurred while I was doing learn C the Hardway.

second case is good. (I get it and accept it)
 
First case it just printed 
Which means you should care (null)%.(How is this (null) coming here suddenly)

Third case prints
Which means you should care %.(it does not cut off at the first occurrence of the \0)

Comment: The `(null)` is simply hardcoded. It's no special conversion or anything like that. The third one should cut off, that's a bit weird to me.

Comment: @Mario and Krishna: no, it shouldn't cut off. The `\0` isn't embedded into the format string. The format string is merely used to interpret the corresponding argument in some manner. And `%c` prints the nul character (i. e. it doesn't print anything), **then it goes on printing the rest of the format string.**

Comment: @Mario Ah, and the `NULL` pointer is not necessarily the address 0x0.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting, wouldn't expect that. As for `NULL`: True, however, that would be just part of the whole `undefined behavior` part there. The whole thing would be based on it assumption after assumption (it could just crash as well, no matter the actual value).

Comment: @Mario Nevertheless, I suggest you update your answer as the explanation of the 3rd case is currently incorrect.

Comment: thanks both of you I am getting it now . @H2CO3 Can you tell in more detail what happens in the case 1 alone once again how it takes it has (null).

Comment: @H2CO3: moreover, `care_percentage` is promoted to `int` when passed to `printf`, but `%s` takes a pointer off the stack, so the argument sizes don't match and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @larsmans Yeah, that's why it's absolutely pointless to reason about anything that happens here... But some guys love assumptions, you know.

Comment: @Krishnasundar It prints `(null)` because `printf()` appears to be checking if the pointer you pass in is a `NULL` pointer. It's a special case with a hard-coded value.

Comment: Consider "Third case: The passed value is read as a character," as "Third case: The passed value, having been promoted to an 'int', is then read and printed as a character,"